# Python. Ошибка при логировании

Tags: python, discord, логирование

Я делал систему `логирования` для своего `discord бота` и столкнулся с новой проблемой: То, что выводится в консоль, сохраняется в файл(как и надо), но несколько раз. Как это исправить?

**Код системы логирования:**

```
import os, sys, logging; from datetime import datetime

def get_file():
    date = datetime.now()
    file_name = str(date.year)
    if len(str(date.month)) == 2:
        file_name = f"{file_name}-{date.month}"
    else:
        file_name = f"{file_name}-0{date.month}"
    
    if len(str(date.day)) == 2:
        file_name = f"{file_name}-{date.day}"
    else:
        file_name = f"{file_name}-0{date.day}"
    
    abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname("logs"))
    if (os.path.exists(abspath) == False):
        os.mkdir("logs")
        file = open(f"logs/{file_name}.txt", "w")
        file.close()

    file_name = f"logs/{file_name}.txt"

    return file_name

def get_logger(name=__file__, file=get_file()):
    log = logging.getLogger(name)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('\n[%(asctime)s] [%(filename)s %(levelname)s]:\n %(message)s')

    fh = logging.FileHandler(file, encoding="utf-8")
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(fh)

    return log

class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, mode):
        self.file = open(name, mode)
        self.stdout = sys.stdout

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()

    def write(self, data):
        self.stdout.write(data)
        self.file.write(data)

    def flush(self):
        self.stdout.flush()
        self.file.flush()

    def close(self):
        if sys.stdout is self:
            sys.stdout = self.stdout
        self.file.close()
```

**Код в каждом файле бота:**

```
import logger as log; import sys
sys.stdout = log.Tee(f"{log.get_file()}", 'a')
sys.stderr = log.Tee(f"{log.get_file()}", 'a')
logg = log.get_logger()
print = logg.debug
```

**Что выводит в файл(в bot_utils.py только 1 print(), без цикла или т.п.):**

```
[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---

[2022-04-18 12:04:42,450] [bot_utils.py DEBUG]:
 ---Коги были загружены---
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Кст, заметил что вы вручную разбиваете файлы по датам. Советую посмотреть в сторону RotatingFileHandler или его аналога: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html?highlight=rotatingfilehandler#baserotatinghandler А вместо `os.path` использовать `pathlib`

Answer (score 1):

Метод [logging.getLogger(name=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) создаст логгер, сохранит по имени и вернет. При повторном вызове вернется ранее созданный логгер.

У вас в функции `get_logger` к логгеру добавляется файловый обработчик на каждый вызов функции.

Можно в самой функции проверить нужно ли логгеру добавлять обработчики, типа:

```
    ...
    log = logging.getLogger(name)

    # Возвращаем уже существующий логгер
    if log.handlers:
        return log

    ...
```